Gregorian Musixtex musixgre package not working: minor line, major line, hypen, alaligne
It is needed to replicate the Gregorian score "Regína Caéli", but some commands are not working; the basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={2pt 5pt 2pt 5pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\input musixlit
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{Re-gí-na caé-li lae-tá-re, a-lle-lú-ia Qui-a quem me-ru-ís-ti por-tá-re a-lle-lú-ia Re-su-rré-xit, sic-ut di-xit, a-lle-lú-ia O-ra pro-nó-bis Dé-um, a-lle-lu-ú-ia.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{4000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\startpiece
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Acordes}%
\notes \squ{MN} \squ{M} \squ{N} \squ{a} \squ{_baN} \squ{_baNM}\en\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\notes \squ{Mccd}\en%
\alaligne%
\notes \squ{c_baMNa_baNM}\en\bar
\notes \squ{ccdccMNMNa}\en%
\alaligne%
\notes \squ{_bc}\en\bar
\notes \squ{cMN_baNMLNNNM}\en\doublebar
\endpiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The desired output is as follow:

Just to remember, the Gregorian notation is as follow:
Gregorian Pause (called minor line, major line):

Note: The pause command is not working (read \shortbarrules\bar), the same with other symbols.

A temporal solution is as follow (using Tikz):
\documentclass[%
border={2pt -7pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\input musixlit
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{Re-gí-na caé-li lae-tá-re, a-lle-lú-ia Qui-a quem me-ru-ís-ti por-tá-re a-lle-lú-ia Re-su-rré-xit, sic-ut di-xit, a-lle-lú-ia O-ra pro-nó-bis Dé-um, a-lle-lú-ia.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{4000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\startpiece
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Acordes}%
\notes \squ{MN} \squ{M}\zcharnote{-2}{\hspace{-1.58cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{N} \squ{a}\zcharnote{3}{\hspace{-1.49cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Punto
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{period}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{_baN}\zcharnote{-2}{\hspace{-1.51cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Guion y raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node (B) [above right = 0.105cm and -1.093cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\scaleobj{1.85}{\lilyGlyph{hyphen}}}}};%Guion
\node [above right = -0.59cm and -0.323cm of B] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};%Raya vertical
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{_b} \squ{a}\zcharnote{0}{\hspace{-1.5cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{NM}\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-1.41cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Punto
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{period}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-0.91cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.0,-0.6) -- ++(0,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\notes\sk \squ{Mc}\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-1.51cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Guion y raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node (B) [above right = 0.08cm and -1.105cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\scaleobj{1.85}{\lilyGlyph{hyphen}}}}};%Guion
\node [above right = -0.56cm and -0.318cm of B] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};%Raya vertical
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{cd}\zcharnote{3}{\hspace{-1.5cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\en%
\alaligne%
\notes \squ{c} \squ{_b}\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-1.385cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{aM}\zcharnote{-2}{\hspace{-1.385cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{Na}\zcharnote{-1}{\hspace{-1.393cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Guion y raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node (B) [above right = 0.08cm and -1.105cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\scaleobj{1.85}{\lilyGlyph{hyphen}}}}};%Guion
\node [above right = -0.56cm and -0.318cm of B] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};%Raya vertical
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{_ba} \zcharnote{0}{\hspace{-1.47cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{NM}\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-1.29cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Punto
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{period}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\en\bar
\notes \squ{cc}\zcharnote{2}{\hspace{-1.395cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{dc}\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-1.393cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Guion y raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node (B) [above right = 0.08cm and -1.105cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\scaleobj{1.85}{\lilyGlyph{hyphen}}}}};%Guion
\node [above right = -0.56cm and -0.318cm of B] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};%Raya vertical
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{cM}\zcharnote{-2}{\hspace{-1.393cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{NM}\zcharnote{-3}{\hspace{-1.393cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Guion y raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node (B) [above right = 0.08cm and -1.105cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\scaleobj{1.85}{\lilyGlyph{hyphen}}}}};%Guion
\node [above right = -0.56cm and -0.318cm of B] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};%Raya vertical
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{Na}\zcharnote{0}{\hspace{-1.393cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\en%
\alaligne%
\notes \squ{_bc}\zcharnote{5}{\hspace{-1.51cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Punto
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{period}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-0.91cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.0,-0.6) -- ++(0,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\en%\bar
\notes\hsk \squ{cM} \squ{N}\zcharnote{-1}{\hspace{-1.665cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{_ba}\zcharnote{0}{\hspace{-1.665cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{NM}\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-1.55cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Punto
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{period}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{LN}\bistropha{N}{N}\squ{M}\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-1.55cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Punto
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\node [above right = -0.2cm and -1.07cm of point] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{\lilyGlyph{period}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\zcharnote{-1}{\hspace{-1.4cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.0,-0.04) -- ++(0,0.54);
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.05,-0.04) -- ++(0,0.54);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\en%\doublebar
\endpiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The output is as follow:


Which "commands are not working" according to you? You want to produce a piece of several lines (using \alaligne) , ignoring that \startextract is meant to start one single line. Use the proper start and ending, then you will see all notes.

Hi Peters, how about minor line, major line and hypen in musixgre, how to implement that?

Do you mean \shortbarrules? For this, the musixdoc.pdf tells you to input musixlit. What do you mean with "hyphen"? Forced hyphenation? Hyphenation depending on the available space?

the \shortbarrules command is not working as expected... see the updated question...

In the manual is written that it "fits" only for 1,2,3 and 5 lines. I am not good enough in programming to change the definition to shorten the bar at the top or to lower the entire bar. The code is in lines 57-62 of musixlit.tex.
